# Taking password of a computer using Hirens boot cd

Tags: boot, passwords, cd

So I have downloaded Hireb's Boot CD in order to reset passwords but this time I dont want to reset it I just want to see it Is it possible that way ?

Windows 7

64 bit

Hiren' boot cd 15.2

thx for your answers

Comment: The only way to get the password on a Windows PC "local" account that I know of is to find the applicable registry HASH for the password, and then you have to either decipher that with software or run it through some online hash decrypter tool that someone else has already done to see if the hash matches a password someone else has gotten with an equivalent hash decypher tool. This task is walking along the fine lines of hacking though so that's all I can tell you. This talks about it some in more detail http://netsec.ws/?p=314 without a lot of detail though on the process.

Comment: Disc-based password tools are generally limited to wiping the password, then you must set a new password once you gain access to the account. To add to what @ModeratorImpersonator notes: Passwords are usually stored as hashes, most often non-reversible. When you type your password it doesn't compare what you've typed, it runs the same hash against what you typed and compares THAT against the stored value. This is prevent people from getting your actual password if they get the hash.

Comment: Although, if you can get the hash and someone else has already set a password, then created a hash for it as tons of online hack forums and tools do, if the hash you have matches a known password hash like these tools do, it'd tell you the password. So I believe what people do is create tons of passwords and then they know the password so they have Windows create the hash, they then use these records to compare other hashes you put in and if that hash matches a record they already have, you know what the password is. I know, people have way too  much time on their hands to create these lists.

Answer (score 1):

With a standard Hiren's Boot CD, it is impossible.

The problem is that **even Windows itself does not know the password.** The password is not stored anywhere. Instead, the password is ran through a cryptographic hash function that creates an irreversible hash from it. That hash is stored. Then, every time you enter a password for logging in, a hash is made from that password and is compared to the stored hash.

There are means called "Rainbow tables" that can crack a hash, but it is rather easy to hinder them with a complex password.

Also, resetting the password with Hiren's Boot CD isn't risk-free. Doing so renders all NTFS-encrypted files inaccessible.

Comment: Nice Answer+1!!! Rainbow tables... I forgot the term but I've seen people do it and I know it is possible. I think it was a 8 year old kid on youtube from China now that I think about it. LOL

Comment: I think computer stores password in C:\Windows\system32\comfig\Sam

Comment: @GameplayerXd It store hashes there. No passwords.